# Is there a way to print the filename of the file that included the current file?

Tags: c++, include, compile-time

Sorry for the confusing title, but I'm not sure of a better way to say it concisely.

Let me break it down with an example to make it clearer.

1. We have 2 files, Foo.h and Bar.h
2. Inside of Foo.h, we have `#include <Bar.h>`
3. Inside of Bar.h, I would like to be able to have something like the following code:

   `#pragma message ("Included from " __INCLUDER_FILENAME__)`
4. At compile time, the message "Included from Foo.h" would appear in the log.

Does anyone know if this is possible and, if so, how to do it?

Comment: There may be pragma to do that, but that would depend on which compiler you are using, which you haven't said.

Comment: MSVC specific: don't think so full list here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard way to do that. Compiler (or rather preprocessor) extensions *may* exist, but that would be tool-chain specific.

Answer (score 0):

### GCC:

Has a `__BASE_FILE__` definition

### Visual Studio:

Go to Project configuration -> C/C++ / Preprocessor.
In Preprocessor definitions add:

```
__BASE_FILE__="%(Filename)%(Extension)"
```

Comment: Is this the "parent" or "root" of the include tree?

Comment: I tried this out and close, but no cigar. This will print the root file in the include tree, which is essentially what was already mentioned.

This won't get me the file that actually included the current file, so it won't accomplish what I need.

Thanks for your answer.